# Php mail function not working properly to the enquiry@travel.com

Tags: php, html

in my web site i have developed a mail function see my code ..

```
$headers='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From:'.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
    $mail_body="";
    $mail_body.='<table style="border:1px solid #993300"  width="400" cellspacing="3" cellspacing="5">';
    $mail_body.='<tr><td style="padding-left:10px; line-height:25px;" >';
    $mail_body.='<center><b>Enquiry Information</b></center><br>';
    $mail_body.='Name :&nbsp;'.$name.'<br>';
    $mail_body.='Email :&nbsp;'.$email.'<br>';
    $mail_body.='Phone Number :&nbsp;'.$phno.'<br>';
    $mail_body.='Package :&nbsp;'.$package.'<br>';
    $mail_body.='Category :&nbsp;'.$category.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Vehicle Type  :&nbsp;'.$vehicle.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Traveling From :&nbsp;'.$travelfrom.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Arrival City :&nbsp;'.$arival.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Date :&nbsp;'.$date.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Adult :&nbsp;'.$adult.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Children :&nbsp;'.$children.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Food :&nbsp;'.$food.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Travel Requirements :&nbsp;'.$requirement.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Duration :&nbsp;'.$duration.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.=' promotions :&nbsp;'.$promotion.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Addons :&nbsp;'.$addone.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='Preferred Destinations :&nbsp;'.$destination.'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.='</td></tr>';
    $mail_body.='</table>';
    $mailSend=mail('enquiry@travel.com', "Country Travelmart" , $mail_body, $headers);
    if($mailSend){
            header("location:success.html");
            }else{
            header("location:sorry.html");
            }
```

I see success.html page, after the mail function. But the mail is not present in 'enquiry@travel.com. I have changed the mail address to my email address, i got the mail. Then why mail is not sent in 'enquiry@travel.com.

Does any one know this?

Please reply

Comment: Did you check the spam folder...?

Comment: Do you check it for another email address too ?

Comment: yes, i have checked with others too(myname@gmail.com). then i got the mail

Answer (score 1):

I think using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) can help you to increase the chanse of preventing emails as spam.

Answer (score 0):

Junk mail? Email being filtered? Does that server that is sending the Email resolve the travel.com to the same IP as you do?

It is apparent that your PHP code does not have an error in it if it is sending to other Email addresses.

Comment: would have been better if this was a comment rather than an answer..!

Answer (score 0):

Some mail servers require certain settings to allow you to email, such as a secure SMTP connection to the server which php cannot handle within its native libraries.

Pear has a library you can use to attach SMTP authentication at: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Additionally, you might wish to troubleshoot by setting your own email address as the sender - in the event of a bounce-back email, you will then be able to receive it and troubleshoot further.

Comment: They already said they get the mail fine when they change the address. But good first step. I'm a fan of PHPMailer. How does it compare to the pear library?

Comment: He gets the mail fine when he changes the 'receiver'. Receiving mail addresses can also be set to deny emails originating without SMTP authentication though.

I haven't used PHPMailer although I've heard it's decent. I have been using the pear lib for 2 years and it has served its purpose very very well :)

Comment: Ahh, change the reply-to would work as well and might come back no matter what.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

If the mail is getting through on other accounts and returning success for this account but never showing up, then the problem isn't with the code, it's with your message getting blocked by the destination server.

Possible reasons:

1. The destination server thinks it's SPAM.  This is almost certainly the case. I worked for a cloud spam service, and web developers using PHP mail and other blind transfer agents hated us.
2. The destination server only allows certain IPs to send (usually a firewall or whitelist).  You probably can't fix this unless you know the IT guy for travel.com and buy them a beer.
3. The destination server rejects messages with specific headers it doesn't understand, aren't set at all, or generally off.

Possible solutions:

1. The only possible solution that would involve keeping your current code in place would be changing or adding a header to the outgoing message. This is probably not the best fix because:

   - The headers could be fine and the message is getting blocked for other reasons.
   - If it is a header, tracking down which one will require getting the message back with the full headers (usually a bounce reply will have them, but not always)
   - Using PHP's mail function is outdated and not ideal for any kind of mail campaigns (for the reasons your seeing)
2. Using a 3rd party mail library like Pear's Mail class or PHPMailer (which I use).  Be aware, however, that the reason these work more reliably is because you provide the SMTP server details and credentials, the same as you would for Outlook or Thunderbird.  PHP's mail function uses the host server's SMTP server to send out, which causes issues like yours, but also doesn't require a password and permission to use.  Having said that, it is better to send via a registered and verified address, both because it's less spammy and because your account's SMTP server can vouch for you, so to speak.  But I would invest in getting an email account just for using in your PHP scripts, rather than using your personal account.  Also, be aware that GMail is  a real headache for this purpose, so just skip it if you can.
3. Dedicated mass mailing accounts, like Amazon SES or MailChimp.  The best of both worlds, because they do bulk mailing better than your SMTP server ever will, it's tied to a user account you set up with them, not your actual email address, and most of them provide PHP libraries.  The catch:  they don't come cheap.  The economics of scale to get a good Return on Investment is tons of emails daily.

My recommendation is to go with a free and respected mailer library and pay (if you aren't already) for a new email address just for the site to send mail.  When it gets to the point where you're sending more emails than your mail server can handle in a day, look at a mass mailer service.